# Sharepoint online 2016 - Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've got a weird issue for only one user.  When 'Mr X' opens Excel locally from SharePoint 2016 Online O365, even when 'Mr X' closes the .xls, other users see same doc as locked for editing by 'Mr X'.
When checking, there is no trace of the .xls being opened on 'Mr X' pc.
Anyone has an idea of the root cause and how can it be fixed?

Thanks.

Comment: I've not seen this exact issue in SP 2013, though I've had docs being locked after a use has edited them.  I'm not sure what causes my issue or yours.  I know SP gets confused and is stuck in a loop.  To fix, ask Mr X to reboot and see what happens.  You might also want to ask admin to attempt to take control of the doc and make a minor edit and save it back to SP.  Maybe this wakes SP up again and clears the error.  Perhaps ask the other users to reboot too if the error persists.

Comment: Haven't tried this but this might help: https://www.puryear-it.com/troubleshooting-locked-documents-sharepoint-office-365

Answer (score 0):

This is because when a document is opened by a office client program, Windows SharePoint Services puts a write lock on the document on the server. The write lock times out after 10 minutes. Users cannot modify the document during the time when the document is locked.

To work around this behavior, wait 10 minutes before you click **Edit in ProgramName** to open the document again.

Refer to : https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/899709/you-receive-a-filename-is-locked-for-editing-by-another-user-message-w .

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue. In my case it was because:
 - to whole company was using Office 365, except Mr.X, he still had the 2016 local package installed. Fixed with uninstall of Office 2016 Apps, and deployment of Office 365 package.